# Maven build - Unable to get resource

Tags: maven

I am doing maven clean build , and I am getting the below exception.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building App
[INFO]    task-segment: [clean, install]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-plugins/10/maven-plugins-10.pom
[WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugins:pom:10' from repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferring file: repo1.maven.org
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-plugins/10/maven-plugins-10.pom
[WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugins:pom:10' from repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferring file: repo1.maven.org
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).


Project ID: null:maven-clean-plugin:maven-plugin:2.2

Reason: Cannot find parent: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugins for project: null:maven-clean-plugin:maven-plugin:2.2 for project null:maven-clean-plugin:maven-plugin:2.2


[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: < 1 second
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Sep 30 12:21:41 IST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 1M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**my settings.xml is as below** ,

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>mirrorId</id>
      <mirrorOf>repositoryId</mirrorOf>
      <name>Human Readable Name for this Mirror.</name>
      <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
```

**and my pom.xml is as below,**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
  <artifactId>ExtJsApp</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>App</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>App</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

any one please help me out of this. I have the same settings.xml in my .m2 folder.

Comment: Sitting behind a proxy? Settings.xml configuration for a repository manager looks wrong ([This is an example which is working for all repository managers](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/maven-sect-single-group.html)).

Comment: I have changed it to http://repo1.maven.org/maven2, but still no luck

Comment: What did you change exactly? repo1.maven.org/maven2 is Maven Central which is used by maven by default. You need to change your settings to use a proxy if you are behind a proxy if not than you don't need a settings.xml configuration.

Comment: I dont have a proxy and I just removed the settings.xml , still same the issue.

Comment: Than remove settings.xml configuration. Do you have a repository manager ?